# Console tool to test internet bandwidth

Tags: utilities, console, bandwidth, testing

I'm looking for a tool that will test my internet connection bandwidth and create an simple report like [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) does.

Do you know some program/tool that do this? Something with CentOS packages would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ttcp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttcp) is a simple, possibly too simple, speed test utility.

[pchar](http://www.kitchenlab.org/www/bmah/Software/pchar/) is another one people cite a lot, I've had bad luck with it, personally.

Here's how I'd use ttcp. You need two machines, each with ttcp (http://playground.sun.com/pub/tcp-impl/ttcp/ttcp.c) compiled on them.

```
HostA % ./ttcp -r -s -p 9401 
...

HostB % ./ttcp -s -p 9401 < /boot/vmlinuz
```

Once you've figured out how to get it to run, try different length files to see how speed varies.  Use UDP (-u flag on both reader and sender command line) for even more fun!

Comment: can you give me an example how to use ttcp?

Comment: If I don't have 2 machines?

Comment: If you don't have two machines, ttcp is worthless.  It just sends a specified number of bytes over TCP or UDP as fast as it cam, and reports how long it took.  Too simple, like I wrote above.

Answer (score 7):

I'm just repeating the answers listed on this (deleted?) stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426272/how-to-test-internet-connection-speed-from-command-line

#### [k2z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548845/k2z):

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli
cd speedtest-cli 
python2.7 speedtest_cli.py
```

Then you have the exact style results from speedtest.net
with cli.

#### [petermolnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673576/petermolnar):

You could use iperf to test the speed between two machines, since 'iperf' was designed to measure bandwidth.

on machine1 (host, this one will receive)

```
iperf -s -p 65000
```

on machine2 (client, this one will upload)

```
iperf -c [ip of server] -p 65000
```

Reverse the machines to test the other way (upload->download or vice versa).

#### [billcarroll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309661/billcarroll):

It looks like there is a tool available on sourceforge that uses speedtest.net from the terminal.

Terminal speedtest: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tespeed/

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [TeSpeed](http://tespeed.sourceforge.net/). It is described as:

> If you are looking for tool that is
>   able to test internet connection speed
>   fron Linux terminal, you have found
>   it! :) TeSpeed uses speedtest.net
>   servers to check upload and download
>   rate and it puts that information on
>   charts.

http://tespeed.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work...

Comment: @wolfy, can you give me some more details? error messages perhaps...

Comment: when I run it, it only print that it starts testing and quit... no error, no info... maybe something in code is missing... I corrected the full path to speedtest.php, but this doesn't helped...

Comment: sounds like it might be dying when it attempts to run curl_init. run "php -m | grep curl" to make sure you have the curl module installed and if not that would be your problem.

Comment: I will try and let you know :)

Comment: OK, now I have curl module, but when it runs I get: download: 0 M/s (but I have 2M)... then testing upload and nothing...

Comment: It has been updated and moved to Github. https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed

Answer (score 1):

Very basic, but I use a simple shellscript to download a 10MB file from my provider or nearby FTP-server:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget ftp://ftp.xs4all.nl/pub/test/10mb.bin ; rm 10mb.bin
## debian.unnet.nl is down...
#wget http://debian.unnet.nl/speedtest/10mb.bin ; rm 10mb.bin
#curl -LO http://debian.unnet.nl/speedtest/10mb.bin ; rm 10mb.bin
```

The output will look like this:

```
($:~)-> speedcheck.sh 
--2011-06-27 23:36:21--  ftp://ftp.xs4all.nl/pub/test/10mb.bin
           => `10mb.bin'
Resolving ftp.xs4all.nl (ftp.xs4all.nl)... 194.109.21.26
Connecting to ftp.xs4all.nl (ftp.xs4all.nl)|194.109.21.26|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/test ... done.
==> SIZE 10mb.bin ... 10485760
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR 10mb.bin ... done.
Length: 10485760 (10M) (unauthoritative)

100%[===================================================>] 10,485,760  1.09M/s   in 9.8s    

2011-06-27 23:36:31 (1.02 MB/s) - `10mb.bin' saved [10485760]
```

Use wget or curl as shown in the script according to your wishes and try to find a server more close to your region (Slovenia).
Most are in NL, but maybe .IT will fit your needs: http://www.filewatcher.com/m/10mb.bin.10485760.0.0.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know how can I measure my upload?

Comment: Try using cURL. Look into the cURL manpage under uploading: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/index.html and improve / enhance the above script yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try http://dl.getipaddr.net

They use curl (which is a well known command line utility) to run a speed test.

The code is published on GitHub as well. In short,

wget https://raw.github.com/blackdotsh/curl-speedtest/master/speedtest.sh && chmod u+x speedtest.sh && bash speedtest.sh

Answer (score 0):

speed testing an internet connection or between two endpoints depends on several factors.
Like 
the window size,jitter,unordered delivery etc.
Refer: [Internet Speed test through Command line](http://www.slashroot.in/iperf-how-test-network-speedperformancebandwidth).

Comment: This would be considered as link only answer. Add more elaborative info from the link to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) tool for this. I created a blog post ([Measure Internet Connection Speed from the Linux Command Line](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2013/03/measure-internet-connection-speed-from-linux-command-line.html)) that goes into detail of downloading, installing and usage of it.

#### Install Git (APT)

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```

#### Install Git (YUM)

```
$ sudo yum install git
```

#### Clone the Repository from GitHub

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli.git
```

#### Sample Usage and Output

```
$ ./speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from Comcast Cable (x.x.x.x)...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by FiberCloud, Inc (Seattle, WA) [12.03 km]: 44.028 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 32.29 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 5.18 Mbit/s
```

Comment: Offtopic, but if somebody has no `git` installed, `wget https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/archive/master.zip` seems easier then installing `git` just to `clone`.